# How to use paddingStart in old android version?

Tags: android, android-layout

its my layout XML :

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:paddingLeft="16dip"
   android:paddingRight="16dip"
   android:paddingStart="16dip"
   android:paddingEnd="16dip"
   android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:fadingEdge="none"
   android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
   android:divider="@null"
   android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

its work well in android 4.2 ! but when i test it on android 2.2 return this error :

```
android-apt-compiler: /group_browse_list_fragment.xml:24: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'paddingStart' in package 'android'
```

how can i resolve this ?

Comment: "when i test it on android 2.2" - The error you posted is something that would happen at compile time. How exactly are you testing on android 2.2? You shouldn't have to compile differently for android 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For example, you’d use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

For more information, [check here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL)